# How to handle exception in async function UWP App GetFileFromPathAsync(path);

Tags: c++, exception, asynchronous, visual-c++, uwp

This code does not catch a AccessDeniedException when it is thrown.

Why?

Not any exception handler will catch it. I have followed the documentation completely.

```
auto fileOp = StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
auto fileTask = create_task(fileOp);    
auto c1 = fileTask.then([](StorageFile^ file) {
             //...
            }).then([](task<StorageFile^> t) {
                try {
                    auto ident = t.get();
                }
                catch (const std::exception &e) {
                    auto msg = ref new MessageDialog("File not found.");
                }
                catch (AccessDeniedException^ e) {
                    auto msg = ref new MessageDialog("Access denied.");
                }
                catch (Exception^ e) {
                    auto msg = ref new MessageDialog("Unknown errer.");
                }
            });
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get the code working, no, but I was able to find a work around using FileIO. I still do not understand what was going wrong here.

Comment: That's weird, my code works well in my side. Have you tried with a new blank C++ project? Or could you please share a [mcve] so that we can know what was going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To handle the exception thrown in `GetFileFromPathAsync` method, you can try with the following code:

```
auto fileOp = StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
auto fileTask = create_task(fileOp);
auto c1 = fileTask.then([](task<StorageFile^> t) {
    try
    {
        StorageFile^ file = t.get();
        ///...
    }
    catch (AccessDeniedException^)
    {
        auto msg = ref new MessageDialog("Access denied.");
        create_task(msg->ShowAsync());
    }
    catch (Exception^ e) {
        auto msg = ref new MessageDialog(e->Message);
        create_task(msg->ShowAsync());
    }
});
```